# Check whether GML contains elevation info?

Tags: qgis, gml

How can I check in QGIS whether a GML file has elevation information, or z coordinates?

It definitely has some overlapping polygons, but I'm not sure whether the ordering of the overlap is specified or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to look at the `pos` or `poslist` elements to see what the srsDimension attribute is - the default is 2 if it is missing.

```
<gml:pos srsDimension="2">45.67 88.56</gml:pos>

<gml:posList srsDimension="2">45.67 88.56 55.56 89.44</gml:posList>
```

Comment: Thanks! No `srsDimension` attribute at all, so I guess it's 2.